# No se usar las apis que ofrece Google Cloud Platform al comprar la cuenta de facturacion

Tags: android

Recientemente se ha comprado la cuenta de facturación en Google Cloud Platform para obtener las apis de rutas y places, pero una vez comprada, intento usarlo en mi aplicación en Android, pero no hay resultados, integre rutas, pero no las dibujaba, solo soltaba un Toast diciendo ERROR: You must use an api key to athenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account y en el fragment de places se cierra automaticamente, no entiendo cual es el error, intente migrar a el nuevo sdk de places, pero en lugar de que se cierre el fragment de búsqueda, se detiene la aplicación, ¿alguna solución?

-Este es el codigo que uso en places:

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                //TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                destination = place.getName().toString();
                destinationLatLng = place.getLatLng();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                //TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        });
    }

-Y esto es de rutas:

private List<Polyline> polylines;
    private static final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.color.primary_dark_material_light};
    @Override
    public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
        if(e != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Algo salió mal, inténtalo de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRoutingStart() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {
        if(polylines.size()>0) {
            for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
                poly.remove();
            }
        }

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();
        //add route(s) to the map.
        for (int i = 0; i <route.size(); i++) {

            //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
            int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;

            PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
            polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
            polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
            Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
            polylines.add(polyline);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ruta "+ (i+1) +": distancia - "+ route.get(i).getDistanceValue()+": duración aproximada - "+ route.get(i).getDurationValue(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRoutingCancelled() {
    }
    private void erasePolynes(){
        for (Polyline line : polylines){
            line.remove();
        }
        polylines.clear();
    }
```